# The system asks for a password

Tags: password

I bought a Dell laptop with Linux Ubuntu preinstalled . After installation, the system asks for a password that I didn 't enter. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "After installation"? You've completed installation? If so, you need to know password you've entered. If no, try to use this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/925971

Answer (score 0):

Whoever had the laptop before you, assuming that it is used, did not factory reset it. I suggest re-installing Ubuntu, as it will take an eternity to actually get the password, Or contact the person who had it before you, if you can. I hope this is a help, and not a hindrance.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, Jeff. I bought A new laptop.